# Why is `make install` always being called?

Tags: makefile

This is my makefile:

```
ifeq ($(PREFIX),)
    PREFIX := /usr
endif

install: libriscy.so.1.0
    install -d $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/lib/
    install -m 755 libriscy.so.1.0 $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/lib/
    ln -s $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/lib/libriscy.so.1.0 $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/lib/libriscy.so
libriscy.so.1.0: riscy.o riscyA.o riscyinit.o
    ld -fpic --shared -o libriscy.so.1.0 riscy.o riscyA.o riscyinit.o -lc -ldl
riscy.o: riscy.c riscyvar.S
    gcc -c -fPIC riscy.c -o riscy.o
riscyA.o: riscy.S riscyvar.S
    as -c -fpic riscy.S -o riscyA.o
riscyinit.o: riscyinit.c
    gcc -c -g -fpic riscyinit.c -o riscyinit.o
```

And this is the current state of the directory:

```
adrian@starfive:~/riscyforth/riscylib$ ls -l
total 112
-rwxr-xr-x 1 adrian adrian 25680 Aug 25 18:16 libriscy.so.1.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 adrian adrian   558 Aug 25 18:05 makefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 adrian adrian 22426 Aug 24 17:41 riscy.S
-rw-r--r-- 1 adrian adrian  3549 Aug 24 17:41 riscy.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 adrian adrian  9560 Aug 24 17:54 riscy.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 adrian adrian 13440 Aug 24 17:54 riscyA.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 adrian adrian  1601 Aug 24 17:41 riscyinit.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 adrian adrian 15520 Aug 24 17:54 riscyinit.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 adrian adrian  1561 Aug 24 17:41 riscyvar.S
```

So why is `make install` being run on every invocation of make - when the dependency `libriscy.so.1.0` exists?

Comment: `make` *always* works toward building one or more goal targets.  If you don't specify one explicitly for a given run, then `make` chooses the first one in the file, which in your case is `install`.  Therefore, if you don't ask for a different target, `make` builds `install`.  Why doing so always results in the recipe for `install` running is a different question, to which your existing answer adroitly responds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but what a rule like this:

```
foo: bar
        recipe
```

means to make is, "if the file `foo` doesn't exist or is older than `bar`, then run the shell and give it `recipe` to update it".

Since your rule for `install` never creates a file named `install`, the rule for the `install` target will always be considered "out of date" (because the file `install` does not exist) and so it will always be run.

Comment: Perhaps the OP's disconnect is related to the fact that `install` is their default target?

Comment: Could be but I don't think so, based on the last paragraph in the question.

Comment: Bit of both, actually - thanks, I'm clearer now